# What does "that" refer to in "Instagram is an online photo-sharing and social networking service that enables..."?

Tags: grammar, relative-pronouns, that

What does the word "that" in the sentence refer to?

> Instagram is an online photo-sharing and social networking service *that* enables its users to take pictures, apply digital filters to it...

Comment: "That" has the nominal "online photo-sharing and social networking" as antecedent, and it functions as subject of the relative clause "that enables its users to take pictures apply digital filters to it ...".

Answer (score 2):

It refers to "an online photo-sharing and social networking service". More specifically, it refers to "service".